# Apply series as row to pandas dataframe with same series in all rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to apply a series to the end of a dataframe, but have the same series in each row of the dataframe. Wondering how I can do this? Example below. Thanks!

Dataframe:

```
   a  b
0  2  3
1  6  5
```

Series:

```
var1    foo
var2    bar
dtype: object
```

Output:

```
   a  b  var1  var2
0  2  3  foo   bar
1  6  5  foo   bar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `assign`

```
df.assign(**s)
Out[354]: 
   a  b var1 var2
0  2  3  foo  bar
1  6  5  foo  bar
```

Comment: Interesting, what does the ** denote? Thanks

Comment: @nicholas.reichel you can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Comment: It works in my test program but its showing nan's in my real program. Any ideas ? https://imgur.com/a/nQBpZql

Comment: @nicholas.reichel Base on my checking, that is one-line data frame , not Series, convert to series , it should work

Comment: @nicholas.reichel yw :-)